# Issues with HTML emails in Thunderbird

Tags: html, email, gmail, thunderbird

I need to make a responsive HTML email and it looks fine in gmail but everything is messed up in thunderbird. I'm using the foundation email framework.

here's an album showing the differences: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABkMh.jpg

The top two images here are what it looks like in gmail, the bottom two are what it looks like in Thunderbird.

This is the HTML for the table which has the top image

```
<table class="float-center wrapper header" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td class="imgbox">
      <img class="mainimage" src= "imgurl" />
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Here's the sass css

```
 .imgbox{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;


    .mainimage{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        position: absolute;

    }
  }
```

I've messed around with the html and css so much, and while it keeps changing on Gmail nothing seems to effect thunderbird.
Is this an issue with Thunderbird? Is there a workaround?

Comment: It would be best to post the code for the email for people to look at or the functional CSS + HTML for the bit that might be causing it.

Answer (score 0):

did you try the classic :

```
body {
    background-color: red
}
```

?

If it does not affect the email on thunderbird, it's probably your cache. You can clear it in Edit>Preferences>Advanced>Network & Disk Space>Clear Now